# How to move files to hdfs in hadoop using unix command

Tags: unix, hadoop, cygwin

I have 2 directories "dft" and "hdfs" in the unpacked Hadoop folder. I am trying to copy the file(StartUnit.txt) in dft into hdfs.
The corresponding command and exception are as shown below

```
313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-0.19.1
$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal D:/eclipse/cygwin/home/313159/hadoop-0.19.1/hdfs              
D:/eclipse/cygwin/home/313159/hadoop-0.19.1/dft/StartUnit.txt

HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
HADOOP_PID_DIR=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
copyFromLocal: Pathname /D:/eclipse/cygwin/home/313159/hadoop-0.19.1/dft/StartUnit.txt 
    from D:/eclipse/cygwin/home/313159/hadoop-0.19.1/dft/StartUnit.txt is not a  
valid DFS filename.
Usage: java FsShell [-copyFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]
```

can someone suggest me...

Answer (score 1):

First the source (local file system) and then the target (HDFS) have to be specified. Run the command as below and it should work.

```
bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir /hdfs
bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal D:/eclipse/cygwin/home/313159/hadoop-0.19.1/dft/StartUnit.txt /hdfs/StartUnit.txt
```

Comment: `hadoop fs -moveFromLocal /home/Desktop/project/data/access-0.log hdfs://localhost:54310 project/data/access-0.log` nothing happen?

Comment: Thanks works in 2020!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved now. Here is the solution.

```
313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-0.19.1

$ bin/hadoop  fs  –copyFromLocal  testdriver/sample.txt  /user/cts/313159/In
```

This command copies `sample.txt` file in the directory testdriver into the hdfs dir In.

If the path `/user/cts/313159/In`, this command creats path and copies the file into it.